# Explicitly constraining which network interfaces are used in ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked this question on the ros discourses, but wanted to put it here as well.

https://discourse.ros.org/t/explicitly-constraining-which-network-interfaces-are-used/5652/2

In raw dds, specifically for coredx, there is a way to give an interfaces list to the domain participant so that it will only talk on those network interfaces. Is there a way to use that through ros2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299940/explicitly-constraining-which-network-interfaces-are-used-in-ros2/) by [nathan.jackson](https://answers.ros.org/users/36880/nathan.jackson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-08-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS 2 API doesn't contain a way to constrain the network interfaces at the moment. You might want to check the specific RMW implementation you want to use and use the vendor-specific configuration to do that (if available).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nathan.jackson](https://answers.ros.org/users/36880/nathan.jackson/) on 2018-08-07**:
Thanks. Is there a specific way you would recommend for the rmw implementation to expose this type of thing?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-08-07**:
In all cases, you'd probably have to use XML files to configure the underlying implementation or else modify our code.

For FastRTPS (our default implementation right now), you might be able to start here: https://eprosima-fast-rtps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pubsub.html#advanced-configuration

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-08-07**:
For Connext, see: https://community.rti.com/kb/how-do-i-restrict-rti-connext-use-only-subset-interfaces

**Comment by [vmanchal](https://answers.ros.org/users/52783/vmanchal/) on 2020-03-23**:
Has there been a support to this in the recent versions of ROS2? Something like Whitelist interfaces by eProsima? https://eprosima-fast-rtps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#whitelist-interfaces

**Comment by [EduardoPonz](https://answers.ros.org/users/61628/eduardoponz/) on 2021-04-06**:
This is already supported in ROS 2 using Fast DDS interface whitelisting https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/transport/whitelist.html. You can also check here how to configure ROS 2 with Fast DDS XML files https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/ros2/ros2.html